# storage of bool in c under various compilers and optimization levels

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, icc

trivial example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    bool tim = true;
    bool rob = false;
    bool mike = true;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", tim, rob, mike);

}
```

Using the gcc compiler it appearers, based on looking at the assembly output, that each bool is stored as a bit in individual bytes:

```
0x4004fc <main()+8>          movb      $0x1,-0x3(%rbp)
0x400500 <main()+12>         movb      $0x0,-0x2(%rbp)
0x400504 <main()+16>         movb      $0x1,-0x1(%rbp)
```

if, however, one turns optimization on, is there a level of optimization that will cause gcc to store these bools as bits in a byte or would one have to put the bools in a union of some bools and a short int?  Other compilers?  I have tried '-Os' but I must admit I can't make heads or tails of the output disassembly.

Comment: No. The smallest addressable unit in C is a byte, that's why we can't really have a real `bool` datatype.

Comment: If storage is at a premium then you could store these three bits in a single char using bitmasks.

Comment: @H2CO3: how about bitfields? anyway, the question was about internal representations, so cannot we have bools in bits, if the compiler decides so (possibly at the cost of additional glue code) ? or does the current standard forbid it ?

Comment: @collapsar: Yes and no; see my answer. But that optimization would save 2 bytes at the cost of (probably) multiple additional instructions to access the individual bits. It's a poor tradeoff unless data storage is very expensive compared to code size (as it might be on some small embedded systems).

Comment: @KeithThompson: you confirmed my hunches. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Keith Thompson's good answer can explain what happened with the code example in the question. But I'll assume that the compiler doesn't *transform* the program. According to the standard, a `bool` (a macro in `stdbool.h` the same as the keyword `_Bool`) must have a size of one byte.

C99 6.2.6.1 *General*

> Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes,
>   the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or
>   implementation-defined.

This means that any type(except bit-fields, including `bool`) of objects must have **at least** one byte.

C99 6.3.1.1 *Boolean, characters, and integers*

> The rank of_Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.

This means `bool`'s size is no more than a `char`(which is an integer type). And we also know that the size of an `char` is guaranteed to be one byte. So the size of `bool` should be **at most** one byte.

Conclusion: the size of `bool` must be one byte.

Comment: ahhh, read the source (document), Luke-- I should have read the C99 standard document

Comment: I think you're missing a step there. How does the fact that `_Bool` has a rank lower than that of `char` imply that it can be only one byte? Why couldn't `_Bool` have, say, 15 or 31 padding bits? There might be a performance advantage to storing `_Bool`s in one word rather than one byte -- whatever a "word" is on a given machine.

Comment: @KeithThompson After a second thought, I think you are right, the lower rank of `_Bool` doesn't mean the order of size. I mis-understood that. I'll delete this anser as long as OP un-accept it.

Answer (score 8):

A compiler can perform any tranformations it likes, as long as the resulting behavior of the program is unaffected, or at least within the range of permitted behaviors.

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    bool tim = true;
    bool rob = false;
    bool mike = true;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", tim, rob, mike);

}
```

(which I've modified a bit to make it valid) could be optimized to the equivalent of this, since the behavior is identical:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts("1, 0, 1");
}
```

So the three `bool` objects aren't just stored in single bits, they're not stored at all.

A compiler is free to play games like that as long as they don't affect the visible behavior. For example, since the program never uses the addresses of the three `bool` variables, and never refers to their sizes, a compiler could choose to store them all as bits within a single byte. (There's little reason to do so; the increase in the size of the code needed to access individual bits would outweigh any savings in data size.)

But that kind of aggressive optimization probably isn't what you're asking about.

In the "abstract machine", a `bool` object must be a least one byte unless it's a bit field.
A `bool` object, or *any* object other than a bit field, must have an unique address, and must have a size that's a whole multiple of 1 byte.  If you print the value of `sizeof (bool)` or `sizeof tim`, the result will be at least 1. If you print the addresses of the three objects, they will be unique and at least one byte apart.

Comment: good answer because it describes exactly what is happening on this specific code...using clang to emit the llvm code is a real winner on that matter. upvote!

Comment: In your usage of "abstract machine" I presume we assume there is no such machine that can address an individual bit; therefore, since byte is the minimum addressable unit, it most store bools (bits) as individual bytes.

Comment: @tallen No, the expression "abstract machine" refers to the wording used by the C standard. The C language targets a so-called abstract machine to describe behavior and to maintain platform-independence.

Comment: "the increase in the size of the code needed to access individual bits would outweigh any savings in data size" Doesn't that depend entirely on the processor hardware and what opcodes it supports?

Comment: @endolith: I suppose so, but code to access a single bit vs. an 8-bit byte has to specify 3 additional bits of information to determine which bit to access. Perhaps those extra 3 bits can be squeezed into the opcode, but in general they're not free.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use a union of bools.  Instead you can say

```
struct a
{
unsigned char tim : 1;
unsigned char rob : 1;
unsigned char mike : 1;
} b;

b.tim=1;
b.rob=0;
b.mike=1;
```

and it would all get stored in a single char.  However, you would not have any guarantees about how it's layed out in memory or how it's aligned.

Comment: I knew there were ways to do it, e.g. bit-fields or unions.  What I didn't understand is why the compiler doesn't "want" to do it.  I think this "abstract machine" concept is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @tallen It doesn't want to do it because it's more complicated and if it wants to extract the boolean values, it will have to perform bitwise operations, which take more instructions than fetching simply loading/storing a byte. C is all for efficiency and simplicity.